# Autosys Running or Not failed/terminated starting condition

Tags: autosys

JobB only should run when JobA is in running status.  Is this possible?

Looking at the starting constraint documentation I can't seem to find a way to do this.

I tried Notrunning(JobA) = False, Notrunning(JobA) = FALSE, Notrunning(JobA) = "False" but it gives and error.